# Display data from database(Entity framwork) into _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developping a web site on MVC3 asp.net and I use entities framwork for data base:
I want to display the logo from database on _Layout.cshtml, and I want to display the texte from database into My home page.
this is my model

```
 public class Theme
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required.")]
    public string ThemeID { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }  
    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is required.")]
    public string texte { get; set; }
}
```

I put in the _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
```

this is my ThemeController.cs

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Header(string id)
    {
        var model = db.Themes.ToList();

        return View("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml", model);            
    }
```

this is the _Header.cshtml

```
@model ICollection<DSClient.Models.Theme>
@{
    <img src="@Href( @Model.ElementAt(@Model-1).path )"  />
}
```

When I type the url of Theme/index
It's OK, BUT the problem is when I load an other page, I have this exception
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Please Ineed your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.Partial` is used to include a partial view. Therefore, when you include `_Header.cshtml` and the Model is not a `ICollection<DSClient.Models.Theme>`, you're in trouble.

Since you made a method with a `Childaction` attribute, I assume you may want to use `Html.Action` instead of `Html.Partial`. This would execute the child action of the controller which outputs the `_Header.cshtml` with the appropriate data.

Remove the `string` argument in the Header action (it's not used) and in `_Layout.cshtml`, you may call it like this:

```
@Html.Action("Header", "Theme")
```

Comment: When I do that, my programm run a lot of time and then declenche this exception An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll in the line var model = db.Themes.ToList(); of the methode Header.

Comment: 2 more suggestions: From the ChildAction, return a `PartialView` instead of a `View`, and review the content of `_Header.cshtml` - it's not clear what the line `<img src="@Href( @Model.ElementAt(@Model-1).path )` is supposed to do (maybe `<img src="@Href(Model.Last().path)` ?)